# What's the difference between $f \cdot g$ and $f(g(x))$?

Tags: functions

For example if
$f(x) = x + 2$
and
$g(x) = 4x - 1$

Then what would be the difference in $f \cdot g$ and $f(g(x))$?

Comment: If the dot is meant to be the composite function then they are the same thing

Answer (score 8):

The notation $f \cdot g$ means that for every $x$ the function is
$$ (f \cdot g)(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x) $$
which  is pointwise multiplication.

On the other hand $f \circ g$ is the composition of functions,
$$ (f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) \ . $$

For your examples:
$$ f(x) \cdot g(x) = (x+2) \cdot (4x-1) = 4x^2 + 8x - x - 2 = 4x^2 + 7x -2 $$
while
$$ (f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) = f(4x-1) = (4x-1)+2 = 4x + 1 \ . $$

Answer (score 3):

If dot means composition then they are the same. $$(f \cdot g)(x) = f(g(x))=(4x-1)+2=4x+1$$
If dot means multiplication then
$$(f \cdot g)(x)=(x+2)(4x-1)=4x^2+7x-2$$

Answer (score 0):

If your interpretation of $\cdot$ is $\circ$ as in $f \circ g(x)$ Then,
$f \circ g(x)=f(g(x))$ which is a composite function. Note that $(f \circ g)(x) \neq (g \circ f)(x)$